# Magento: getDescription() on product gives null

Tags: php, magento

I have a little problem with Magento and I am trying to figure what's wrong for one hour and there is no end.

```
$this->_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1565);
$desc = $this->_product->getDescription();
```

I have code like this. It's very simple, but getDescription function gives me null (also shortDescription). My product model don't have information about description (in back panel this product have both - description and short description).

Is there something that I should add to this function? I read few topic and every of them proposes code like my to get this description.

Comment: Check your attribute for description and short_description. Are they both set to Visible on Product View Page on Front-end = Yes?

Comment: if you var_dump($this->_product->getData()); is the description there?

Comment: I found my problem. Later in code I had: $this->_product->setStoreId(0)->setStatus($status) - only for one store, all my products were edited before with this. So my description changes was visible only for back panel. I added setStoreId(1) for front-end store and it works now. Thanks to sulman with pointing me to look at front-end view.